# How to see unread emails only in Gmail's Inbox?

Tags: gmail

Up until two days ago, my "Inbox" in Gmail has only shown unread emails at the top, with the read ones being shown somewhere near the bottom.

For some reason, this has changed. While my "Inbox" tab still shows "32" next to it, on the right hand side I can now see all emails, including unread ones. But I'd like for my inbox to only show those 32 unread ones:

[image]

Googling for this has led me to the following URL: http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/30/show-unread-messages-gmail/. They suggest the following filter:

```
label: inbox, label: unread
```

This shows exactly what I want, but I'd like for this to be the default view, and not have to apply a filter each time.

Any idea how I can switch back to the old view'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- left-click the number at your Inbox folder and choose your preference:

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thank you!